# Various paint objects in Activity

Tags: android, canvas, paint

I'm dealing with a canvas where I have to draw several elements of different types, thus several different paint objects. What I want to know is which is more efficient, creating different pain objects or setting different configurations to the same one

Comment: Obviously, there will be more overhead with more Paint objects. However, it makes code easier to read/debug if your Paint objects are not changing after initialization. As long as you are not doing the object creation in `onDraw` it shouldn't really matter either way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's bad for performance to instantiate objects at the onDraw method (where you are using the Paints), i'm not sure about changing values.

But the usual approach would be to instantiate the Paint objects before and just use each one in its onDraw part.